# relation between algebraic geometry and complex geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

As a complex manifold $\mathbb{P}^n$ is  locally the euclidean space $\mathbb{C}^n$, as a projective variety it is locally $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the Zariski topology, as a scheme it is locally $\text{Spec}(K[x_1,\ldots,x_n])$. It is well-known that the projective variety $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the set of the closed points of the scheme $\mathbb{P}^n=Proj(K[x_0,...,x_n])$. Is there any inspiring connection, e.g., between the goemetry of $\mathbb{P}^n$ as a scheme and the geometry of $\mathbb{P}^n$ as a complex manifold; more generally is there any inspiring connection between algebraic geometry(scheme theory) and complex manifolds?

Comment: A projective variety, even smooth, is, as a a rule, *not* locally $\mathbb C^n$ with Zariski topology.

Comment: The famous GAGA paper of Serre explains this connection.  You cen get this  paper  here  http://aif.cedram.org/aif-bin/item?id=AIF_1956__6__1_0

Comment: Existence (As finite étalé quotient of Hilbert Scheme) of moduli Space of Complex or Kähler Manifolds led to study of Scheme theory. For example, existence of moduli Space of log- Calabi Yau Manifolds still an open problem.

Comment: Study of "Douady space " play an important role in connection between Algebraic Geometry and Complex Geometry.